How to replace values in a dictionary with keys in another without repeats?
I'm working on a task in Python where I need to replace elements within sets, which are values in one dictionary (my_dict), with the keys from another dictionary (dict_vals). Each key in dict_vals is associated with a set of values. If a value from a set in my_dict is found within any set of dict_vals, that value should be replaced with the corresponding key from dict_vals. Importantly, each set within my_dict should not have duplicate elements after the replacement.
Given dictionaries:
my_dict = {0:{2,3}, 1:{0,4,5}, 2:{0,1,5,7}}
dict_vals = {'val1':{1,2,3},'val2':{7,8}]

But deleting any repeats within each key to get this:
my_dict = {0:{'val1'}, 1:{0,4,5}, 2:{0,'val1',5,'val2'}}

My approach was to iterate through my_dict, check if any value is a key in dict_vals, and then attempt to replace that value with the corresponding set from dict_vals. Here is the code I've tried, but it doesn't change my_dict:
keys_replace = dict_vals.keys()
for key in my_dict.keys():
    for i, val in enumerate(my_dict[key], 0):
        if val in keys_replace:
            index_to_replace = keys_replace.index(val)
            my_dict[key][i] = dict_vals[keys_replace[index_to_replace]]

I'm new to working with dictionaries, especially those containing sets as values, and I suspect my approach might be flawed due to a misunderstanding of how to access and replace set elements. Could you provide guidance on how to correctly achieve the desired output, and explain where my logic went awry?

Can you manually type the output you want to achieve? I'm not able to understand. You want to replace the switch the values of my_dict with keys of dict_vals?

I want to replace the values in my_dict with the keys wiht the same values from dict_values, if that makes sense?

If the value in the dict is a set you won't have any duplicates

@user18692484 okay I understand but here in this example there aren't any matching values from both the dicts if I'm not wrong. Or you just want to see, if the value in my_dict are present in the values of dict_val

This will only reliably work as you like, if each member of the sets in my_dict is unique amongst the members of the values in dict_vals in order to translate any given integer to one and only one key-string like "val1". For instance, if your dict_vals was like {'val1':{1,2,3},'val2':{1,7,8}}, then for the integer 1, you could either replace it with val1 or val2 and the result would become ambiguous.
So, under the assumption, that relevant set-items in dict_vals will be unique to a particular key, you have the option to create a reverse of dict_vals:
dict_rev = {val:k for k,v in dict_vals.items() for val in v}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    s = set()
    for value in v:
        try:
            s.add(dict_rev[value])
        except KeyError:
            s.add(value)
    my_dict[k] = s

Note: If the previously given assumption wasn't the case, then you'd first need to decide how to decide which "valX" you want to choose among those that have the same integer in their set.

Try:
my_dict = {0: {2, 3}, 1: {0, 4, 5}, 2: {0, 1, 5, 7}}
dict_vals = {"val1": {1, 2, 3}, "val2": {7, 8}}

tmp = {}
for k, v in dict_vals.items():
    for i in v:
        tmp[i] = k

my_dict = {k: {tmp.get(i, i) for i in v} for k, v in my_dict.items()}
print(my_dict)

Prints:
{0: {"val1"}, 1: {0, 4, 5}, 2: {0, 5, "val1", "val2"}}

